# Problem with priority_queue - Writing memory after heap

Tags: c++, queue, heap-memory, priority-queue, heap-corruption

I am trying to use priority_queue, and program constantly fails with error message HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED.

here are the snippets:

```
class CQueue { ...
              priority_queue<Message, deque<Message>, less<deque<Message>::value_type> > m_messages;
...};
```

class Message has overloaded operators > and <

Here I fill up queue:

```
CQueue & operator+=(Message &rhv)
{
    m_messages.push(rhv);  //This is where program fails
    return *this;
}
```

and in the main program:

```
string str;
CQueue pq;
for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
{
    cin >> str;

    Message p(str.c_str(), rand()%12); //Create message with random priority
    pq += p;                           //add it to queue
}
```

I have no idea what seems to be the problem. It happens when I push about 8 items, and it fails on line

```
    push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
```

in < queue >

:(

Here is the definition of message class - it's very simple:

```
#pragma once 

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

 class Poruka
{
private:
char *m_tekst;
int  m_prioritet;
public:
Poruka():m_tekst(NULL), m_prioritet(-1){}

Poruka(const char* tekst, const int prioritet)
{
    if(NULL != tekst)
    {
    //  try{
            m_tekst = new char[strlen(tekst) + 1];
        //}
        //catch(bad_alloc&)
    //  {
    //      throw;
    //  }


        strcpy(m_tekst, tekst);
    }
    else
    { 
    //  try
    //  {
            m_tekst = new char[1];
    //  }
    //  catch(bad_alloc&)
    //  {
    //      throw;
    //  }

        m_tekst[0] = '\0';
    }
    m_prioritet = prioritet;
}

Poruka(const Poruka &p)
{
    if(p.m_tekst != NULL)
    {
        //try
        //{
            m_tekst = new char[strlen(p.m_tekst) + 1];
        //}
        //catch(bad_alloc&)
        //{
        //  throw;
        //}

        strcpy(m_tekst, p.m_tekst);
    }
    else
    {
        m_tekst = NULL;
    }
    m_prioritet = p.m_prioritet;
}

~Poruka()
{
        delete [] m_tekst;
}

Poruka& operator=(const Poruka& rhv)
{
    if(&rhv != this)
    {
        if(m_tekst != NULL)
            delete [] m_tekst;

    //  try
        //{
            m_tekst = new char[strlen(rhv.m_tekst + 1)];
        //}
        //catch(bad_alloc&)
        //{
        //  throw;
        //}

        strcpy(m_tekst, rhv.m_tekst);
        m_prioritet = rhv.m_prioritet;
    }
    return *this;
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& it, const Poruka &p)
{
    it << '[' << p.m_tekst << ']' << p.m_prioritet;
    return it;
}

//Relacioni operatori

friend inline bool operator<(const Poruka& p1, const Poruka& p2)
{
    return p1.m_prioritet < p2.m_prioritet;
}

friend inline bool operator>(const Poruka& p1, const Poruka& p2)
{
    return p2 < p1;
}

friend inline bool operator>=(const Poruka& p1, const Poruka& p2)
{
    return !(p1 < p2);
}

friend inline bool operator<=(const Poruka& p1, const Poruka& p2)
{
    return !(p1 > p2);
}

friend inline bool operator==(const Poruka& p1, const Poruka& p2)
{
    return (!(p1 < p2) && !(p2 < p1));
}

friend inline bool operator!=(const Poruka& p1, const Poruka& p2)
{
    return (p1 < p2) || (p2 < p1);
}
```

};

Poruka - Message

Comment: If you are going to use `using namespace std`, don't name your own classes the same things as classes in `namespace std` (cf. `queue`).

Comment: can you add the definition of Message class?

Comment: Adam's answer looks good but we can't be sure he is right unless you post the full definition of Message.

Comment: FOUND IT:

m_tekst = new char[strlen(rhv.m_tekst+ 1)];

:/

Thank you!

Comment: stupid typo - two hours on this :(

Comment: Another reason to use std::string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `Message` objects are keeping pointers to raw C strings which are then getting deallocated.  In these lines:

```
cin >> str;

Message p(str.c_str(), rand()%12);
```

On each iteration of the loop, you're reading in a new value to `str`, which invalidates any old pointers returned by its `c_str()` method, so your older messages are pointing to invalid data.  You should change your `Message` object so that it stores its string as an `std::string` instead of a `char*`.  This will properly copy the string into the `Message` object.

Alternatively, if you can't change the `Message` class, you'll have to explicitly copy the string yourself, e.g. using `strdup()` or `malloc()`/`new[]`+`strcpy()`, and then you have to remember to deallocate the string copies at some later point.

Comment: No. This is not true. He correctly copies the raw strings (which surprised me)

Comment: @Martin York: I posted my answer before he posted the definition of the Message class, so I was only guessing that he didn't copy the string.  But it looks like he managed to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it to fail.
But there is not enough info to compile this line:

```
push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
```

But the only problems I see are:

1) You have a default constructor that could create a Poruka with a NULL name:

```
Poruka::Poruka():m_tekst(NULL), m_prioritet(-1){}
```

2) Not a problem because you test for it most places but in the assignment operator you miss a test:

```
Poruka::Poruka& operator=(const Poruka& rhv)
{
 ....
    // There was no test for 'rhv.m_tekst' being NULL here.
    //
    m_tekst = new char[strlen(rhv.m_tekst + 1)];
    strcpy(m_tekst, rhv.m_tekst);
```

Notes:

- You could make your code much simpler by using the std::string class.
- If you still want to use char* then if you gurantee it is never NULL then the code is simpler
- Also there is a simpler patter for defining the standard copy constructor and assignment operator. It is refered to as the copy/swap idium.
- You dont need to define all those relational operators. There is a set of template ones that work automatically in  see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/operators.html. You just need to define operator< and operator==

Here is an example of the copy/swap idium

```
class X
{
     X(X const& copy)
     {
          // Do the work of copying the object
          m_tekst     = new char[strlen(copy.m_tekst) + 1];
          ...
          m_prioritet = copy.m_prioritet;
     }
     X& operator=(X const& copy)
     {
         // I like the explicit copy as it is easier to read
         // than the implicit copy used by some people (not mentioning names litb)
         //
         X  tmp(copy);  // Use the copy constructor to do the work

         swap(tmp);
     }
     void swap(X& rhs) throws ()
     {
         std::swap(this->m_tekst,   rhs.m_tekst);
         std::swap(this->prioritet, rhs.prioritet);
     }
```